# Should you go for computer science if you aren’t interested in it?

Tags: undergraduate

I am from India and am preparing for the JEE exam for admission to engineering colleges in India.

I am very much interested in physics, chemistry, biology, and maths. I am not interested much in computer science. But my family says you can only get a job with BTech in computer science but will not get from BSc in basic sciences. I have done C++ and Java as well before. I just don’t find them as interesting as basic sciences. How should I choose my career in engineering and need to get a job after BTech?

I am very much interested in behaviour of light, cells, electricity, and time.

They also say that from electrical engineering, you can’t get a good job after BTech.

Also, if I understand a concept clearly, I am very good at relating it to real-life examples.

Comment: I am not sure that this site is the right place to answer this question for two reasons: 1) Here we try to answer general, objectively answerable questions. Yours is very subjective. 2) There are few here who can give you career advice outside of academia. Maybe you want to reformulate the question, for example, if one can follow a science career after doing a BSc in IT etc Also, what is BTech?

Comment: @Greg bachelors of technology

Comment: As it stands it is like asking my parents do not like my girlfriend. Shall I stop the relation with her? Nobody can or is even willing to answer.

Comment: I also talked about earning ? What you wrote does not match my question @Alchimista

Comment: Note that C++ & Java != CS, which encompasses much more than (and is most cases not actually) programming.

Comment: You need serious personal advice, but this isn't the place for it. Talk to a counselor at your school or a trusted teacher or other adult advisor. Consider both family and professional things. Think long term about what you want and need.

Comment: @user102532 my meaning is that you are the only one who knows how much things value for your. Other would be asking which discipline offers more job opportunities and the likes.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your kind answers.I have interest in mechanical , electrical engineering for now. But in India , you just don’t get a good Job here . You can say as I have seen the salaries of students who under-graduated from top institutes like IIT in India.Salary in hand is like 1000 dollars. And these branches , most of the times, even the major companies do not come to appoint them.

Answer (score 7):

The situation in India may vary from my experiences, and the situation in times of a pandemic may vary from my experiences. Therefore, it is unclear how definitive any answer to your questions can be. But these are my two cents:

You should not go for any major that you're not interested in.

A degree from any of the fundamental sciences sets you up for many interesting jobs. From my math class, every one who graduated and wanted to find a good job, did find a good job.

Comment: Signed. Even jobs you love can become annoying with repetition. And one never knows what the situation will be after a decade - you might study something that everybody says will be job-secure, and in ten years, these jobs will be wiped out by AI or whatever new development.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do a course you're not interested in. You might find it difficult to fully commit to but if you do something you enjoy you'll do well at it and have greater satisfaction with your life.

Comment: Sorry, but this is facile advice. Overly optimistic about the possibilities. It assumes an ideal world. Not this world.

Comment: Marvinated_mia Please expand upon your answer. You could probably start by saying why you disagree with Dr @buffy

Comment: @TejasShetty, instead let me explain further. The advice here is actually what I believe is the correct action, but it may not be able to actually do and may cause problems. One of the issues here is that in some cultures and in some families it may not be feasible to go against your parent's advice. For both financial and personal reasons. We need to respect that. The other, which the OP doesn't explain is whether they just want "a job" or "a career" or "something life fulfilling". The "job" part may be necessary, not optional. If they were looking for a career in academia I'd have (cont)

Comment: some different advice, since it is possible to start on one path (making mom & dad happy) and changing later when you are more independent. But that requires a long term view and the ability to follow it. That isn't open to everyone depending on basic requirement and cultural norms. That is why I suggest to the OP that they find someone they trust with whom they can be completely open and explore all of the options. Unfortunately this site isn't designed to give such advice.